# 8-bit char to Hex representation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert 8 bit `char` into hex view which looks like this:

```
00 03 80 45 E5 93 00 18 02 72 3B 90 88 64 11 00 
45 FF 00 36 00 FF 45 00 00 34 7B FE 40 00 40 02
```

But some characters contain negative values which makes a larger hex value of more than 2 digits. how would i get each one as represented above?

Comment: bytes into hex view? as a string? I don't understand

Comment: Simply put, an integer to hex value.

Comment: that doesn't make sense. hexadecimal is simply a notation for an integer, as is binary, octal, decimal, the list goes on.

Comment: Just change the wording of the problem and replace bytes with 8-bit chars (which are signed) and that will make the question make much more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you are using for formatting, but make sure that you make your byte holding variable an unsigned char (assuming that char is 8-bits on your platform, which it is on all sane platforms), before formatting. If your platform has a sane BYTE typedef, use that. You can also use the `boost::uint8_t` type to store the byte and avoid these sorts of issues. For example:

```
char c=-25; // Oh no, this is one of those pesky "negative" characters
unsigned char byteVal=static_cast<unsigned char>(c); // FTFY

// Do the formatting with byteVal
```

Comment: Ah i see, I was directly converting a char to unsigned int.

Comment: Don't do this, convert through an unsigned char or other unsigned 8-bit type before going to unsigned int. Otherwise, you get sign extention and a nasty large value (e.g., -1 becomes 0xFFFFFFFF if your unsigned int is 32-bits). Please, don't forget to accept the answer if it fully answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, now I will remember to convert a signed byte to unsigned byte.

Comment: Or better yet, store all your bytes in the appropritate unsigned 8-bit type for your platform (or use boost::uint8_t).

Comment: I cannot edit my comment but I meant signed 8 bit char to byte.

Comment: @user45355: For better or worse, "char" (in all 3 variants) is synonymous with "byte" in C++. :)

Comment: I've also seen BYTE being unsigned char in c++.

Answer (score 0):

"negative byte values" is an oxymoron, a byte is a number of bits without any sign typically an unsigned char which, when being 8 bits. can contain values 0-255 or in hex 00 to FF.

Comment: An interesting comment, but doesn't address the OP's real problem of getting negative values (in the unseen code).

Comment: He meant that some (8-bit) characters contained negative values which when converted to hex via an unsigned int resulted in large hex values, per his comment to my answer.

Comment: Actually i had char type which holds negative value but I called it a byte.

Comment: A "signed byte" is a perfectly cromulent thing to talk about; and I'd argue that a "signed character" is a *less* sensible concept (but, sadly, one we are stuck with)

Comment: The non-sensible thing was not distinguishing between "byte" and "character".  It made *some* sense before Unicode, but now...