# Qt hex representation of a negative 8bit int?

Tags: c++, qt

*[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012480/8-bit-char-to-hex-representation) however, I'm looking for a qt solution.*

I'm looking for a way convert a 8 bit negative int into a hex representation. The example will explain it better.

```
qint8 width = - 100;
qDebug() << QString::number(width, 16);

// "ffffffffffffff9c"
```

The output is much more than 2 bytes.

However, when i change it to unsigned, it works fine.

```
quint8 width = - 100;
qDebug() << QString::number(width, 16);

// "9c"
```

The documentations states:

> typedef quint8
>
> Typedef for unsigned char. This type is guaranteed to be 8-bit on all
> platforms supported by Qt.

---

> typedef qint8
>
> Typedef for signed char. This type is guaranteed to be
> 8-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.

Shouldn't unsigned not be able to deal with negative numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `QString::number` can accept `int` or `uint` types. It doesn't have versions for 8-bit integers, so they are implicitly casted to larger integers. It works fine with signed integer because leading zeros are removed.

You can however use `QDataStream`, it provides `operator <<` for large variety of types:

```
QByteArray buffer;
QDataStream stream(&buffer, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
qint8 width = - 100;
stream << width;
qDebug() << buffer.toHex(); 
// output: "9c"
```

Answer (score 1):

`QString::number` only takes `int`s and `long`s so both times `width` was promoted to a qint and quint resp

Unsigned promotion does not extend the sign bit while signed promotion does.

and documentation of [QString::number says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#number)

> The base is 10 by default and must be between 2 and 36. *For bases other than 10, n is treated as an unsigned integer.*

that means the extended sign bits are displayed